# How to create a GUID column? I tried string with :length => 36 but is created varchar(255)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a database field to store a GUID.

I did this:

add_column :users, :user_guid, :string, :length => 36

But it just created a column of varchar(255)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails doesn't have *length*, it have **limit**

```
add_column :users, :user_guid, :string, :limit => 36
```